# How to set color differently whenever time is >= 12, fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

i'm building a control access, i'm tryng to render events (when personal leave or/enters the building), to be red when the personal leave's , and blue (default color) when he arrives, i'm rendering the fullcalendar this way;

```
$sql = "SELECT tiempo.entradas,tiempo.ficha as start FROM tiempo WHERE '$ficha' = tiempo.ficha  "; 
        $result = $connect->query($sql);
        $output = array();
        $output2 = array();
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {             

         while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $entry=$row[0];
    //  $output = array();
        $output[] = array('start'=>
            $entry);
        }
```

and the JS fullcalendar code:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      titleFormat: { // will produce something like "Tuesday, September 18, 2018"
        month: 'short',
        year: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        weekday: 'short'
      },
     weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',
            locale: 'es',
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid'],

          timeZone: 'UTC',
          allDaySlot: false,
          defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
            minTime: '00:00:00',
            maxTime: '20:00:00',
       slotLabelFormat: {
            hour          : 'numeric',
            minute        : 'numeric',
            omitZeroMinute: false,
        },
        events: <?php echo json_encode($output); ?>,

  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',

  },



});

    calendar.render();
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to include only the relevant code (i.e. you can remove all of your PHP database queries) and make this a complete example (i.e. replace your  `json_encode()` with actual example JSON). Additionally, please include the relevant HTML so we can see the real functionality. Preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (or JS fiddle or something equivalent) so we can see the JS actually run.

Comment: In the PHP, check the time of the event, then add a suitable colour property to the event object. See here for the name of the colour properties you can use to control a fullCalendar event's colours: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing